# how do I install android studio for window 7, 32bit

Tags: android, windows, operating-system

how do I install android studio for window 7, 32bit.?
I've downloaded the package for Windows(32-bit) and it comes in a zip file containing a lot of other files like bin, gradle, jre, lib, license, plugins, and I don't know what to do with them, I looked up for .exe file to install the android studio but the only .exe I found was the uninstall file.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is late, but I just thought it may help some one in the future.

Once you've unzipped the folder to a location on your computer.
There is a file in the bin directory named studio.exe it will have the android icon
Just double click the studio.exe file to start Android Studio, it will first take you through the set up process and download a few packages before you can start developing so make sure you have a stable internet connection.

It could be slower to develop on a 32-bit system because of memory constraints, but it still can be used, to make development slightly faster you can build debug apk's and upload to a real device rather than an emulator or use adb(android debug bridge) from a terminal to test and run your app as you develop it.

Comment: 32-bit systems will no longer be able to be used with future versions of Android Studio, so be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Is recommended to use a 64bit operating system, becaouse it uses more of memory.

Check this link, and click on the green button to download it.
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html